# In Wordpress function.php's hook, how to retrieve the short URL of the current post correctly?

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress `function.php`, I have following code to get the short URL of the current post:

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'save_cf7_data');
function save_cf7_data($cf) 
{
    $post_url = 'https://' . $_SERVER[ 'SERVER_NAME' ] . $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ];
    $post_id = url_to_postid( $post_url );
    $post_shorturl = wp_get_shortlink($post_id);
}
```

It used to work perfectly without any problem for months. However, there must be some changes in contact form 7 plugin or Wordpress, `$post_url` starts to return url like this:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/108/feedback
```

How to retrieve the short URL of the current post correctly in this case?

Comment: Did you debug what you get on your `$post_url` variable. Rest of code should be working fine.

Comment: @mlbd you are right, it actually returns something else, not expected (it worked earlier though). I have modified the question content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function save_cf7_data($cf) {
  $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
  $cf_url = $submission->get_meta( 'url' );
  $cf_postid = url_to_postid( $cf_url );
  $cf_shorturl = wp_get_shortlink($cf_postid);
}

add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'save_cf7_data');
```

See the file [mail.php](https://github.com/wp-plugins/contact-form-7/blob/721fd1d81ff871d359f61131f34307970795b412/includes/mail.php#L294) in source code of CF7.

Have a look at the [Special Mail Tags](https://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/), specifically `[_post_url]` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [get_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) for retrieving post url in a page template. `functions.php` may load before global `$post` is set, not too sure.

**EDIT:**

Oh if you look at the `$post_url` you got, it's actually a WordPress Rest API url. So I think the form plugin used to submit to the original page but now chooses to use WordPress Rest API.

But your solution is not the correct approach in the first place. Since this is a form submission, you should do a dump of the `$_REQUEST`. I bet there's form's post url info in there. If not submitted by default, you can probably add a post url (most likely hidden) field in the plugin form.

Comment: I tried, but `get_permalink()` gives me `0` instead.

Comment: It's definitely get_permalink() would be not working here, because it's fired after cf7 form.

Answer (score 0):

Then try like this,

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'save_cf7_data');
function save_cf7_data($cf) 
{
    global $wp;
    $post_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
    $post_id = url_to_postid( $post_url );
    $post_shorturl = wp_get_shortlink($post_id);
}
```

Comment: I just tested it, but `$post_url` still returns an URL like the one in the question, not the post URL.